# performSegueWithIdentifier not working if called from viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, segue

I have a simple app with a loading screen. Here I check for some user details in NSUserDefaults and jump to either the login or the sign up screen.

The viewDidLoad() for the loading screen looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadingVM = LoadingVM() as LoadingVM

    print("LoadingVC")
    checkStoredUser()
}
```

Here is the checkStoredUser()

```
func checkStoredUser()
{
    storedUserStatus = loadingVM.returnStoredUserStatus()

    if(storedUserStatus == true)
    {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("loadingToLoginVC", sender: self)
    }
    else
    {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("loadingToSignUpVC", sender: self)
    }
}
```

As you can see, I decide where to go from here based on what the loadingVM.returnStoredUserStatus() returns. I am sure this returns what it's supposed to return but nothing happens.

Here is the prepareForSegue()

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    print("prepareForSegue")

    if(segue.identifier == "loadingToSignUpVC")
    {
        let signUpViewCotroller = (segue.destinationViewController as! LocalSignUpVC)
    }
    else if(segue.identifier == "loadingToLoginVC")
    {
        print("loadingToLoginVC")

        let loginViewCotroller = (segue.destinationViewController as! LoginVC)
    }
}
```

I did some digging and found a weird suggestion that seems to be working but It's not very practical not to mention right to do it like this:

```
func checkStoredUser()
{
    storedUserStatus = loadingVM.returnStoredUserStatus()

    let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue())
    {
        if(self.storedUserStatus == false)
        {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loadingToSignUpVC", sender: self)
        }
        else
        {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loadingToLoginVC", sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me what's going on here, why doesn't this work and how to make it work properly? It's the first time I encounter this and I can't seem to be able to find any info on this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**EXPLANATION:**

Your View hasn't appeared yet when you call your `checkStoredUser()`.

**EASY FIX:**

Put it in `viewDidAppear()` like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated:Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(false)
    checkStoredUser()
}
```

Comment: That was simple :)). I thought that if I can call a function from viewDidLoad, say doStuff(), it would be OK to perform a segue from doStuff() but I guess it makes sense. Thanks