# Not performing segue

Tags: ios, swift

I am testing a simple login system for an iOS app.

This is the code where I want to check if the user was logged in previosly:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let logeado = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "logeado")
        let men = "SI"

        if logeado == men {
            showToast(message: logeado!)
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "entrar_segue", sender: self)
        }


    }

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "entrar_segue"{
            var vc = segue.destination as! HomeViewController

        }
    }
```

The Toast is shown, but the segue is not performed. There is a button that uses the same function:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "entrar_segue", sender: self)
```

and there it works.

What is wrong in the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317683/performseguewithidentifier-not-working-if-called-from-viewdidload You may have an error console message saying something like "can't present view is not in hierarchy".

Comment: @InderKumar as the OP mentioned, if there is a button calls `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "entrar_segue", sender: self)` and it works, then the identifier should be correct.

Comment: @InderKumar, thank you, but as said in my question the segue is performed by another method

Comment: @Larme what you mentioned is right, but I prefer the accepted answer for this question, instead of calling it in the `viewDidAppear` method...

Comment: @mvasco can you show us the code from where you moved to current controller (having your above code)?

Comment: @InderKumar, what do you mean?

Comment: @mvasco See I can feel that you're moving to the current controller from a background thread and hence your view did load is running on bg thus your  `performSegue(withIdentifier: "entrar_segue", sender: self)` is not working there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call this `self.performSegue` method in `dispatch_async` block:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "seg", sender: self)
    }
}
```

That's because `viewDidLoad()` runs in background thread and all UI updates and transitions must be done on Main Thread.

Comment: I don't have this block in my code, how should I implement your proposal?

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async {`
`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "entrar_segue", sender: self)`
 `}`

Comment: Could you mention how `DispatchQueue.main.async` solves it?

Comment: ViewDidLoad runs in background thread and all UI updates and transitions must be done on Main Thread. That’s how DispatchQueue on Main thread solves it.